# Why does Script editor not like this edit?

Tags: firefox, safari, applescript

I got his script:

```
   set vURL to URL of current tab of window 1
end tell

tell application "Google Chrome"
   if windows ≠ {} then
       make new tab at the end of window 1 with properties {URL:vURL}
   else
       make new window
       set URL of (active tab of window 1) to vURL
   end if

   activate
end tell
```

I'd really like to be able to just quickly open the tab I'm using in Safari in Firefox beause...

I'm told have to add more text here so, Skip this paragraph. ... a site I use a lot has some great features in Firefox but it can be slow to load so I like to switch backwards and forwards between the two.

Why won't it work if I change "Google Chrome" to "Firefox":

```
tell application "Safari"
    set vURL to URL of current tab of window 1
end tell

tell application "Firefox"
    if windows ≠ {} then
        make new tab at the end of window 1 with properties {URL:vURL}
    else
        make new window
        set URL of (active tab of window 1) to vURL
    end if

    activate
end tell
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix and match scripting terms - the scripting terminology (if any) for a given application is entirely up to the developer and is unique to that application.  There also isn't a standard or common practice for term names, so any similarity between scripting terms of different applications would be purely coincidental and wouldn't necessarily provide the same functionality.

Looking at the scripting dictionaries for **Google Chrome** vs **Safari** and **Firefox**:

- **Firefox** doesn't really have a scripting dictionary, only a default suite is available.  Specifically, a window does not have either
  `tab`, `active tab`, or `URL` elements (`URL` here would also be
  assumed to be from **StandardAdditions**)
- **Safari** windows do not have an `active tab` property.

You will need to target each application with its own `tell` statement, using the terminology specific to that application.  Also note that trying to do something like using a variable to hold the application name will not work, since the scripting terminology for each application is looked up when the script is compiled.

#### (Edit from comments)

To open the URL of the current **Safari** tab with **Firefox** (version 69.0.1 in Mojave), you can do something like:

```
tell application "Safari" to set theURL to (get URL of current tab of front window)
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    open location theURL
end tell
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. Let me reword the question. Could anyone give the right information I need to to make a script to open just the open tab from Safari in Firefox?

Comment: Edited my answer to add an example.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.